# Oracle The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionStringBuilder' threw an exception

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

First off, my knowledge of Oracle databases is pretty limited. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and trying to configure Oracle as a Data Provider. I have successfully managed to configure SQL Server.

I installed the following Nuget Packages:

- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

To clarify, I don't want Oracle Client to be installed on any computers that I would deploy my software on. So, I read that Oracle's packages will provide this functionality.

What I'm trying here, is to construct a connection string:

```
 // Construct the Oracle Connection String
OracleConnectionStringBuilder oracleConnectionStringBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
```

When I execute the code, I get the following exception thrown:

> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionStringBuilder' threw an
>   exception.

And InnerException:

> The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

I read somewhere that I should install the Oracle Instant client but from my understanding this should be included in the Nuget Packages.

Comment: Can you check and post the inner exception.

Comment: Updated the post, didn't take a look at it, thanks for the heads up. Still don't know what it means though.

Comment: Just noticed the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` in the exception message. Looks like you are referencing another Oracle component. Replace all `using Oracle.DataAccess.Client.*` with `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.*`

Comment: Oh my god that was it! I was using the Microsoft Oracle DataAccess before and didn't think about updating the namespace